# Can you read the success message from executed SQL in a procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a JavaScript stored procedure that executes a "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS..." statement. How can I read the message the statement returns and find out if it created the table or if the table already existed?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! There's a result set returned when you execute a SQL statement from inside a Snowflake stored procedure, and one of the columns is named "status" (all lower case). Reading that gives you the message that says whether the table was created or already exists:

```
create or replace procedure create_table()
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
    cmd1 = {sqlText: 'create table if not exists temp_test(id int)'};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1);
    rs = stmt.execute();
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue('status');
$$;

call create_table()
```